# Account owner not able to add Account Team

Tags: account, ownership, account-teams, sales

I'm facing a issue where an Account Owner is not able to add Account Team Member.
He is able to see all the users but still after clicking Add Team Member button, option to select user is not visible.
Is there any permission needed to add Account Team Member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these things:-

1. To add team members to an account:  Read on users AND Edit on accounts
2. Who can manage the account team members depends on the users’ access. Account record owners and users above the owner in the role hierarchy can add, edit, and delete team members.
3. Your page layout of account team member determines which fields are visible and your access to the account determines which fields are editable.

Reference:- [Account Team Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=accountteam_fields.htm&type=5) and [Add Account Team Members](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=accountteam_add.htm&type=5)

Comment: It was page layout assignment issue, looks like for Account team member salesforce never assign default page layout

Comment: You can mark it as accepted if it has solved your problem.